# How to merge lines of a list into phrases (help to complete the code)?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list as follows:

```
[
 '"The investment would also benefit the company’s',
 'ongoing commitment to the Kraft Foods Sustainability Programme; substantially reducing material',
 'usage by replacing cardboard boxes with reusable',
 'plastic tote bins and cutting daily vehicle movements through the accurate management of',
 'fixed cyling schedules.",',
 '"The core brands of Cadbury Roses and Heroes are',
 'produced and packaged at the Bournville production facility. The wrapped chocolates that make',
 'up these assortments have traditionally been',
 'managed through the factory in cardboard boxes.'
]
```

I need to drop `"` and merge lines into phrases in order to get the following result:

```
[
 'The investment would also benefit the company’s ongoing commitment to the Kraft Foods Sustainability Programme; substantially reducing material usage by replacing cardboard boxes with reusable plastic tote bins and cutting daily vehicle movements through the accurate management of fixed cyling schedules.',
 'The core brands of Cadbury Roses and Heroes are produced and packaged at the Bournville production facility.",
 'The wrapped chocolates that make up these assortments have traditionally been managed through the factory in cardboard boxes.'
]
```

How can I do it?

This is what I started doing:

```
final_list = []
temp_list = []
for l in lines:
    temp_list.append(l) 
    if "." in l:
        phrase = ' '.join(map(str, temp_list)) 
        final_list.append(phrase)
        temp_list = []

final_list
```

It generates the following output, which is not exactly a match of my expected output:

```
[
 '"The investment would also benefit the company’s ongoing commitment to the Kraft Foods Sustainability Programme; substantially reducing material usage by replacing cardboard boxes with reusable plastic tote bins and cutting daily vehicle movements through the accurate management of fixed cyling schedules.",',
 '"The core brands of Cadbury Roses and Heroes are produced and packaged at the Bournville production facility. The wrapped chocolates that make',
 'up these assortments have traditionally been managed through the factory in cardboard boxes.'
 ]
```

Comment: Your given input has " quotation marks and a comma at the end. You are also getting the extra line because you are testing for a period anywhere in the input.

Comment: @thshea: What do you mean by `you are testing for a period anywhere in the input`? The code and inputs are reproducible. I don't have any hidden code and inputs.

Comment: What criteria are you supposed to use to join the strings? It seems underspecified currently, so you're implementing one approach (use periods to detect sentence boundaries) where the expectation seems to be something different (maybe using the parentheses?).

Comment: @Blckknght: The strings should be joined until the dot `.` is found. Once the dot is found in a string, the new phrase should be started.

Comment: What happens with this: `and packaged at the Bournville production facility.`? It has a dot

Comment: @Fluxy: That doesn't match the expected output you show, which has a full stop in the middle of the second line.

Comment: @Blckknght: Oh, I see. My bad. Please see the updated expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It will check only if there is a period near the end, and it will remove the extra quotation marks and comma that you remove in between your test and output case, but will not remove extra characters.

```
final_list = []
temp_list = []
for l in lines:
    temp_list.append(l) 
    if "." in l[-3:]:
        phrase = ' '.join(map(str, temp_list)).strip('", ')
        final_list.append(phrase)
        temp_list = []

print(final_list)
```

Comment: This gives me only `fixed cyling schedules.", managed through the factory in cardboard boxes.`

Comment: Sorry, left a debugging line in. Edited version should work.

Comment: This works well. Thanks. The only issue that I see in my full dataset is that some phrases start with `' "`, for example: `' "The device is equipped with ...`

Comment: Then `strip()` the spaces from `l` before doing anything to it. @Fluxy

Comment: do you mean adding `l.strip(" ")` before `temp_list.append(l)`?

Comment: I added that to the `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. `lines` is the name I gave to the array.

```
for i in range(1,len(lines)):
lines[0] += " " + lines[i]

lines = [line.split("\"")[1] for line in lines[0].split(", ")]
print(lines)
```